# How to determine what visual attributes are being applied to an element, and where they come from?

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF app that has a page with a couple of RadGridViews that are bound to collections.

The odd thing is that some of the rows, but not all, are showing up with pink backgrounds, and I don't know why.

I haven't set any styling on the gridviews, and I'm not aware of any special styles being set on the bound elements.

And I'm at a loss as to how to figure out what, in the code, is setting this visual styling.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've been walking the visual tree in snoop, and finding nothing.

Comment: I've found the style - there is a Border element named Background_Invalid defined for every cell that is visible for the elements that are pink and invisible for the elements that are not. Clearly the problem is that the DataContext is failing some sort of validation for some rows and not for others.  I'm at a loss, though, as to why.

Answer (score 0):

I would ctrl+f on that xaml file and any styles that it is using until I find a pink color; then on the whole solution if need be.

Comment: That's less than useful.  Tell me, what would you enter into a search dialog that would find "pink"?

Comment: Just trying to help Jeff. Something, somewhere, must be setting a .Color property on the elements that you speak of (or whatever template you are using for that element is is setting .Color). I'm not sure if you wrote this code (I'm assuming not), but you might also check if the element is binding to a property on it's DataContext that is setting it.

Comment: The property in question was Background, the color was a specific hex triplet that looked pink to the eye. but which isn't textually obvious as pink.  (Can you think of a regex that will match all pinkish RGB strings?)  And the template that was setting that Background is buried in a third-party DLL to which I don't have source.

Comment: Not having access to the source code and a dll setting the properties in question sound like important details to me.